# Detailed description of malware content

Tags: malware

I have just started my journey into the vast and intersting field of malware analysis. I would like to know if there is any website/book or another resource that explains what a particular block of assembly code does. A detailed description of the code would be well appreciated. I know assembly language to some extent and is familiar with all the concepts,function call procedure etc. But i have very little knowledge on how all these applies when it come to windows. like what happens when a dll is used,etc... I would be very glad if someone could tell me where to find a resource that provides a step by step detailed analysis of any malware or any program for that matter.

I have already a considerable experience in reverse engineering windows applications, most of the knowledge been taken from the 'legend of r4ndom' and woodman websites. I need something that clearly explains how a particular assembly code interacts with windows dlls, resources like menu bars text boxes, etc..

Comment: Sounds like you need something like "Programming Windows" or "Windows Internals" rather than reverse engineering-specific information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend You to start from basics, so:

1. ["Windows Internals"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx) by Mark Russinovich and David Solomon is a good start for hard copy book.
2. [OpenSecurityTraining](http://opensecuritytraining.info/Training.html) - start from Beginner's courses by interest

When You done with those - I am sure You'll be able to ask more specific questions and get more detailed and sophisticated answers.
Good luck!